# Modal window jQuery, Javascript not working

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I use jQuery modal window and it works fine, but when I want to include website into modal window with code

```
$("#vsebina").load('validField.html');
```

the Javascript that validates form doesn't work any more.

I put examples below. Click push button to open modal window. Try just to put some  letters in input field an click out of input field and you'll get error.

Example one (basic jQuery code with modal window): [link](http://www.oliviers.si/test/validForm/form_elementsValidModal.html)

Example two (modal window that uses `.load()` function: [link](http://www.oliviers.si/test/validForm/form_elementsValidModalLoad.html) - In this option Javascript doesn't start and I don't get desired error.

Where is mistake, cause I've been searching this for hours.

Comment: In the 2nd example you load some HTML you want to validate via AJAX - is that correct? If yes, maybe you have to wait until the content is loaded an then add your event handlers for the validation.

Comment: No. Actualy I want to load html form to add user data, and validate user inserted data with javascript. Ajax requests will come later, but they aren't part of this.

Comment: 404 Not Found - http://www.oliviers.si/test/validForm/form_elements.html?ageField=df". Check the resource

Comment: Well they are. http://api.jquery.com/load/ Load is performing ajax methods. Go into your demo.js and write alert('$("#mws-validate").length'); before $("#mws-validate").validate({ and tell me what number it spits out. If it is 0, then I was right with my guess.

Comment: Yes it spits 0 out. So does this mean cause there isn't ajax request in field it stops script and that's the reason I don't get validation. If this is the case should I use .get() or what?

Comment: @Suoulbe It's true that this link isn't included in example, but it's irrelevant cause sumbit isn't part of my question, just validation. Still I changed link to "#"

Comment: No, it simply means by the you want to bind the validation plugin the element you want to bind it to doesn't exist. And that's because you're loading the element via ajax which is asynchronous. Use $.get().then() and bind the validation plugin in the then() callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `$( "myForm" ).validate()` inside the `click()` function and after the `load()` function.

Your html is not present when the script is loaded. Therefore, validation code is not attached to your form and you never do it later.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards

Comment: That's it, works. Thank you very much ph. Now I just have to put this into my original app.